# Almost Gaussian distribution with interesting moments

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, moments

I have a rather funny situation here. There is this random complex number, $z$, with an unknown distribution $\rho_\lambda(z)$ which depends on a parameter, $\lambda$.

I can compute the moments and they are given by 
$$\langle z^n\rangle=\frac{n!p(n)}{\lambda^n},$$ where $p(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$. The first few are $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, $\frac{4}{\lambda^2}$, $\frac{18}{\lambda^3}$,...

I suspected the distribution was approximately Gaussian for large $\lambda$, and this turned out to be true. Gaussians are very good approximations to the distributions of the real and imaginary parts of $z$, as I show in the figures below (for $\lambda=10$).

[image]

The real part is approximately distributed according to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-(x-1/\lambda)^2}$  and the imaginary part is approximately distributed according to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-y^2}$. The first moment in this case is also $1/\lambda$.

However, these distributions cannot be correct, even asymptoticaly, as they do not give the correct moments for $n>1$,
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int dxdye^{-y^2-(x-1/\lambda)^2}(x+iy)^n =\frac{1}{\lambda^n}.$$

I know I am asking for a lot, but does anyone have any idea what is going on? What could the actual distribution of $z$ be like?

Comment: Can you add details as to how you determined the moments?  I asking about the moments equaling $n! p(n)/\lambda^n$.

Comment: @JimB That is a whole other calculation, involving group theory. I prefer to omit the details. But I have checked those moments numerically and they agree with data.